# Admob reward video match rate very low

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm having trouble trying to identify why my rewarded video adunit has so low match rate...

I've 4 ad units on my app... each of them stands for one size of ad
banner, large_banner, medium_rectangle and rewarded video
these are the statistics from admob

[image]

as you can see all banner related adunits are performing fine, they have above 80% match

but the rewarded unit has 10x more requests and 10x less match rate

According to googles doc:

> It is highly recommended that you call loadAd() as early as possible
>   (for example, in the onCreate() method of your Activity) to allow
>   videos to be preloaded.

So I do, on oncreate() of every activity which uses rewarded ad i try to load it, and since not necesseraly it will be shown i believe that the non shown videos are accounting for the low match rate

I've tryed several times reaching google's support but they are pretty useless, either they dont understand nothing about the tools they provide or they are not willing to investigate

I also strongly believe this is pushing my ecpm down somehow, because before i intruduced the video reward the others adunits had an higher ecpm

does anyone know something about it? is there a best practice for loading video ads? thanks for the help